# Android: Dagger 2.4 not working with ButterKnife 8.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, butterknife

I'm working on an Android app that uses both Dagger 2.4 and ButterKnife 8.0.1. The app works fine if I use only Dagger, but as soon as I add ButterKnife dependencies on my build.gradle, the compiler doesn't find Dagger generated classes anymore.

These are my dependencies:

```
// Dagger 2 dependencies
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.4'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.4'

// Butterknife dependencies
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
```

I suppose the problem is caused by both compilers clashing, but I don't have a very good knowledge of Gradle.

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: This might be the reason: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/349

Comment: Since I'm using it with apt they should not be put on classpath but on processorpath instead... Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the problem myself. It wasn't actually related to a dependency conflict but to a view binding in a private field. Removed that, the build worked like a charm.